# Is this "glitch safe" clock mux really glitch safe?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga, hdl

I found this design for a clock mux at http://www.vlsi-world.com/content/view/64/47/1/1/

The author claims that it is glitch safe, but I think that it could still have a glitch if the routing delays for the clock signal to the respective or gate (or_three, or_four) was greater than the routing delay + clock to out delay of q3/q4 to the or gate when the output of q3/q4 went low. In order to avoid these glitches, the outputs of q3/q4 would have to have go high on the clock's rising edge and go low on a clock falling edge. Am I correct in this assessment?

Also note that the schematic on the page I linked doesn't quite match the verilog (q3's qbar output isn't used in the verilog) and that the testbench used to generate the simulation transposes clk_a and clk_b.

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps

module clk_switch (
   // Outputs
   out_clk,
   // Inputs
   clk_a, clk_b, select
   );

   input clk_a;
   input clk_b;
   input select;

   output out_clk;
wire   out_clk;

reg q1,q2,q3,q4;
wire or_one, or_two,or_three,or_four;

always @ (posedge clk_a)
begin
    if (clk_a == 1'b1)
    begin
       q1 <= q4;
       q3 <= or_one;
    end
end

always @ (posedge clk_b)
begin
    if (clk_b == 1'b1)
    begin
        q2 <= q3;
        q4 <= or_two;
    end
end

assign or_one   = (!q1) | (!select);
assign or_two   = (!q2) | (select);
assign or_three = (q3)  | (clk_a);
assign or_four  = (q4)  | (clk_b);

assign out_clk  = or_three & or_four;

endmodule
```

I wrote up a quick translation in VHDL so clever folks who are more familiar with that language will be able to check it and nobody will take issue with a VHDL tag on here.

```
entity clk_switch is
   port(
      out_clk : out std_logic;
      clk_a   : in  std_logic;
      clk_b   : in  std_logic;
      sel     : in  std_logic;
   );
end clk_switch;

architecture rtl of clk_switch is
   signal q1 : std_logic;
   signal q2 : std_logic;
   signal q3 : std_logic;
   signal q4 : std_logic;

   signal or_one   : std_logic;
   signal or_two   : std_logic;
   signal or_three : std_logic;
   signal or_four  : std_logic;
begin
   process(clk_a)
   begin
      if (clk_a'event and clk_a='1') then
         q1 <= q4;
         q3 <= or_one;
      end if;
   end process;

   process(clk_b)
   begin
      if (clk_b'event and clk_b='1') then
         q2 <= q3;
         q4 <= or_two;
      end if;
   end process;

or_one <= not q1 or not sel;
or_two <= not q2 or sel;
or_three <= q3 or clk_a;
or_four  <= q4 or clk_b;

out_clk <= or_three and or_four;

end rtl;
```

Comment: This section looks odd to me `always @ (posedge clk_a) if (clk_a == 1'b1)`, as posedge will only trigger when `clk_a==1'b1` so seems a redundant statement and I do not think it would reliably change the output of synthesis (different tools could handle it differently, ie add mux/ignore it).

Comment: There's a metastability path from `select` thru `or_two` and `q4` that requires q4 metastability recovery during the high baud of `clk_b`.  The same holds true for `not select` thru `or_one` and `q2`, both cases for an arbitrary switch on `select`.  It's a clock speed limitation, half the possible flip flop speed minus the `or_one` or `or_two` gate and routing delays to allow for metastability recovery. Overcoming the speed limitation requires a longer no-clock period (more flip flops, re-clocking `select`).

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the metastability issue, but assuming that select met the setup/hold of the active clock (the one where it actually changes the value of or_one/or_two) could it cause a glitch? I think so but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: The gating 'off' thru`or_three` or `or_four` occurs when the respective clock is high, the new clock enabled when it is high. `or_three` and `or_four` De Morgan equivalent AND gates. `out_clk` a De Morgan OR gate product.  Within the metastability recovery imposed flip flop speed limit it should be glitch free.  Each clock depends on the other clock being disabled before enabling.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and created a testbench and simulation for the VHDL translation with a small (10 ps) routing delay on `clk_b to or_four`. Of course, in a real FPGA there will be several delays on the `q4/C to or_four` path, but the routing delay of `clk_b to or_four` could still potentially be longer. The whole gating of the output would also be absorbed into a single 4-input LUT, but that wouldn't change this output behavior.

The glitch I was worried about can be seen here near 480 ns: [image]

Can anybody think of a reason that this wouldn't/couldn't happen on target? Would static timing analysis prevent this?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity clk_switch is
   port(
      out_clk : out std_logic;
      clk_a   : in  std_logic;
      clk_b   : in  std_logic;
      sel     : in  std_logic
   );
end clk_switch;

architecture rtl of clk_switch is
   signal q1 : std_logic;
   signal q2 : std_logic;
   signal q3 : std_logic;
   signal q4 : std_logic;

   signal or_one   : std_logic;
   signal or_two   : std_logic;
   signal or_three : std_logic;
   signal or_four  : std_logic;

   signal clk_b_routed : std_logic;
begin
   clk_b_routed <= clk_b after 10 ps;

   process(clk_a)
   begin
      if (clk_a'event and clk_a='1') then
         q1 <= q4;
         q3 <= or_one;
      end if;
   end process;

   process(clk_b)
   begin
      if (clk_b'event and clk_b='1') then
         q2 <= q3;
         q4 <= or_two;
      end if;
   end process;

    or_one <= not q1 or not sel;
    or_two <= not q2 or sel;
    or_three <= q3 or clk_a;
    or_four  <= q4 or clk_b_routed;
    out_clk <= or_three and or_four;
end rtl;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity tb_clk_switch is
end tb_clk_switch;
architecture testbench of tb_clk_switch is
    component clk_switch is
        port(
            clk_a   : in  std_logic;
            clk_b   : in  std_logic;
            out_clk   : out std_logic;
            sel     : in  std_logic
        );
    end component;

    signal clk_a : std_logic := '0';
    signal clk_b : std_logic := '0';
    signal out_clk : std_logic := '0';
    signal sel   : std_logic := '0';
begin
    clk_a <= not clk_a after 10 ns; --periods arbitrary
    clk_b <= not clk_b after 23 ns;
    sel   <= not sel   after 200 ns;
    uut : clk_switch
    port map (
        clk_a => clk_a,
        clk_b => clk_b,
        out_clk => out_clk,
        sel   => sel
    );
end testbench;
```

Comment: That's one way to artificially cause a problem.  It doesn't show Q4 holder over/output delay from clk_b.  It's easy to imagine q4 and or_four straddling two different branches on a clk_b clock tree or otherwise having your 10 ps delay on clk_b to the or_four.  It's a little bit more unlikely that q4 has a zero output delay or that the q4 to or_four routing delay is also 0.   It's not fair to have a partially timed model or in the case of a timed model to not have timing constraint targets, this is a clock after all.

Answer (score 0):

***...I think that it could still have a glitch if the routing delays for the clock signal to the respective or gate (or_three, or_four) was greater than the routing delay + clock to out delay of q3/q4 to the or gate when the output of q3/q4 went low.***

This may clarify a bit.

[image: show De Morgan equivalents of gates on clocks]

The image can be zoomed viewed separately, it's larger than it appears here. As Dr. Emmett Brown might say, I apologize for the crudeness of the model, it was the only schematic editor I had handy.  The purpose is to show the De Morgan gate equivalents, showing that the clocks are gated while high, the output delay for q3 and q4 from the rising edge of their respective clocks, q3 and q4 have the remainder of their respective clock's high baud for output delay and clock routing delay.

And as discussed in the comments to the question there's a metastability path from select through or_one or or_two to the D input of q3 or q4 with respect to the particular clock, where if one or both clocks are not related to select (sel in the VHDL source), the metastability recovery time of q3 or q4 has to be less than the the high baud of their respective clocks, should the gated select fail to meet setup or hold time for the affected flip flop.  It's a clock speed limitation that can be cured by increasing the no-clock is enabled period between operating from the two clock domains.

Comment: I absolutely agree with the clock speed limitation on the clock to be disabled due to the asynchronous select. I'm more concerned with when the new clock to be activated (after both clocks are disabled) is released from gating at nearly the same time as the clock rises.